# UI freezed instead of showing BusyIndicator in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

This is a side-related question to this other question:
[BackgroundWorker in Silverlight ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528486/backgroundworker-in-silverlight-viewmodel)

I have a TabControl where I load many TabItems when the user selects menu options. I load this Tabs by binding the TabControl ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection. When I add a new TabItem to this Collection, it is shown perfectly.

The problem is I've realized that since user press a button until the tab is created (ViewModel and View creation takes a couple of seconds), the screen is freezed.

I've tried to set "IsBusy" before calling the "loadTab" but it doesn't shows up... I've tried almost everything with async calls but the UI thread is in use and it throws an exception when I create the new tab control.

Is there any trick I'm loosing??? Any ideas??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you seen this post?

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/3524-doesnt-your-girlfriend-deserves-more-time.aspx

It helps when you avoid heavy stuff in the load event and make Visible=true after you finish to load all your resources, so in that sense you avoid the user feeling tempted to click something that is not ready yet.

Not sure if it helps, but how about this idea?

```
public void DoStuff(Object values)
{
//your values object could be anything, 
//they might even be some objects from your form
//as long as you dont modify them in the other thread
imgLoading.Visible=true;
var client = new Proxy();
client.OnWorkCompletedAsync +=client_OnCompleted() ;
client.Work(values);
}

void client_OnCompletedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgLoading.Visible=false;
    //now you can update the UI with other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use WCF asynchronous calls in my application but this is a "local call". It takes a little while to create the View and the ViewModel and the screen just "freezes" meanwhile. I want to show a busyindicator to let the user know that something is happening.

Comment: what I mean is that you can still use another background thread to do heavy lifting (not only when you are calling services), after calling the background thread you can provide a useful UI effect

Comment: That's just what I'm trying, but it throws me an UnauthorizedAccessException when I try it (please see my other question). Thanks for your answer :)